# How to remove all MySQL tables from the command-line without DROP database permissions?

Tags: mysql, command-line, sql-drop

How do I drop all tables in Windows MySQL, using command prompt? The reason I want to do this is that our user has access to the database drops, but no access to re-creating the database itself, for this reason we must drop the tables manually. Is there a way to drop all the tables at once? Bear in mind that most of the tables are linked with foreign keys so they would have to be dropped in a specific order.

Comment: A similar question has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476765/mysql-drop-all-tables-ignoring-foreign-keys?lq=1

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command/8912749#8912749

Comment: It seems OP is asking to drop all tables from the command prompt, not from MySQL (as it's on the linked question), so in my opinion it's not duplicate.

Comment: See also: [How to drop all MySQL tables from the command-line?](http://superuser.com/q/308071/87805).

Comment: None of the linked question are the same as this one. This question is not duplicate!

Comment: Asked the question 2 years ago, and still think it's not a duplicate one, mainly because most of the other answers simply drop the database and re-create it. However it was specifically said that one does not want to drop the database itself

Comment: @Mantas Just voted to reopen this as I don't think it is a duplicate either and the accepted answer is far better than the one in the duplicate. If anything, the duplicates should be inverted.

Answer (score 332, accepted):

You can generate statement like this: `DROP TABLE t1, t2, t3, ...` and then use prepared statements to execute it:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; 
SET @tables = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('`', table_schema, '`.`', table_name, '`') INTO @tables
  FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'; -- specify DB name here.

SET @tables = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @tables);
PREPARE stmt FROM @tables;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Well this needs a bit of tweaking as it cannot drop the tables that are constrained by keys

Comment: This works fine if we SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; and do SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; after deletion this will allow us to delete all tables without having key checks;

Comment: That is because DROP TABLE drops tables one by one, and doesn't bother of dependent objects (related tables). So FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS should help.

Comment: NB It may also be necessary to increase `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN` and to escape the schema and name with ``GROUP_CONCAT('`', table_schema, '`.`', table_name, '`')``.

Comment: I'm running this, and got strange errors: `ERROR 1051 (42S02) at line 9: Unknown table 'catalog_catego'`. There is no such table in my DB, but the real name of table is `catalog_category` - it looks like the last two chars were eat. It happens only for some tables. Any idea?

Comment: I found, the problem was `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN` I have a lot of tables. I edited your answer to have these variables set. Thank you to @PeterTaylor too!

Comment: I added the small improvement to the query, in case when there is no tables on the database. If no, the current script will rise the mysql error with NULL value.

Comment: CONCAT "DROP TABLE " must includes " IF EXIST ", this has been reduced my time.

Comment: This is not the best solution.  @Kostonos fixed an important issue with this command and edited Devart's answer, but it was not accepted.  Please see Kostanos' answer on this page. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18625545/114558)

Comment: @rinogo The answer should give an idea for people. Then you can change/edit any solution to make it the best for you.

Comment: I get 500 status code (rejected)

Comment: MySQL is a usability nightmare :/

Answer (score 295):

The @Devart's version is correct, but here are some improvements to avoid having error. I've edited the @Devart's answer, but it was not accepted.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=32768;
SET @tables = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('`', table_name, '`') INTO @tables
  FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_schema = (SELECT DATABASE());
SELECT IFNULL(@tables,'dummy') INTO @tables;

SET @tables = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', @tables);
PREPARE stmt FROM @tables;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

This script will not raise error with NULL result in case when you already deleted all tables in the database by adding at least one nonexistent - "dummy" table.

And it fixed in case when you have many tables.

And This small change to drop all view exist in the Database

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=32768;
SET @views = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('`', TABLE_NAME, '`') INTO @views
  FROM information_schema.views
  WHERE table_schema = (SELECT DATABASE());
SELECT IFNULL(@views,'dummy') INTO @views;

SET @views = CONCAT('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ', @views);
PREPARE stmt FROM @views;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

It assumes that you run the script from Database you want to delete. Or run this before:

```
USE REPLACE_WITH_DATABASE_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_DELETE;
```

Thank you to Steve Horvath to discover the issue with backticks.

Comment: Actually, it does raise an error.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? Which error did you get?

Comment: My mistake, it's actually a warning because 'dummy' tables doesn't exists.

Comment: I don't get this warning. If you see on the query it does `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`

Comment: Yes, precisely. For some reason my 5.6 install gives a warning on those if the table doesn't exists.

Comment: Any way it is better then an exception which I got when the database was already cleaned, the @tables is NULL on that case, this when we need add dummy table, to have something on that list.

Comment: for the overly cautious, `SELECT @tables\G` after the last SELECT above will give you a listing of what's about to be dropped - look over it before executing the second half of the snippet

Comment: A tiny issue with both solutions is that the backticks are missing from around the table names, which can throw things out.  The other solution is easier to edit for this effect, though.

Comment: @SteveHorvath could you please give me an example of a table name, that could break this store procedure? I would like to test it and to improve the function. Thanks.

Comment: @Kostanos sure: "group" for example, but any reserved word will do.

Comment: @SteveHorvath thank you to pointing the issue with backticks. I fixed the query and it runs perfectly now with (group, select and other tables).

Comment: This is the proper answer

Comment: Still not working: `#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'information_schema'`, Any idea?

Comment: I can't manage to change foreign_key_checks = OFF when I run it on Mariadb. It throws an error. In Heidisql gui it shows off as a background color, but if I set it ON it shows it bright blue. I think it's a permissions. i can set them outsdie procedure. And I didn't find much documentation on this either

Comment: I don't get the *error problem*, which is supposed to be solved by `SELECT IFNULL(@tables,'dummy') INTO @tables;`: *This script will not raise error with NULL result in case when you already deleted all tables in the database by adding at least one nonexistent - "dummy" table.* So the script in the accepted answer does always raise an error - but why exactly?

Answer (score 92):

Try this.

This works even for tables with constraints (foreign key relationships). Alternatively you can just drop the database and recreate, but you may not have the necessary permissions to do that.

```sh
mysqldump -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] \
  --add-drop-table --no-data [DATABASE] | \
  grep -e '^DROP \| FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS' | \
  mysql -u[USERNAME] -p[PASSWORD] [DATABASE]
```

In order to overcome foreign key check effects, add `show table` at the end of  the generated script and run many times until the `show table` command results in an empty set.

Comment: Wish I could vote this up twice. So simple and plays really nicely with environments like AWS Beanstalk where everything comes in from env vars anyway. Just `mysqldump -h$RDS_HOSTNAME -u$RDS_USERNAME -p$RDS_PASSWORD --add-drop-table --no-data $RDS_DB_NAME | grep -e '^DROP \| FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS' | mysql -h$RDS_HOSTNAME -u$RDS_USERNAME -p$RDS_PASSWORD $RDS_DB_NAME`

Comment: A very neat solution

Comment: Love the idea. Here's the same thing for all database a user have access to:
`mysqldump --host=127.0.0.1 --all-databases --user=$mysql_user --password=$mysql_password --add-drop-table --no-data | grep -e '^DROP \| FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS\|USE' | mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=$mysql_user --password=$mysql_password`

Answer (score 50):

You can **drop** the `database` and then **recreate** it with the below:-

```
mysql> drop database [database name];
mysql> create database [database name];
```

Comment: As I said the user has no permissions to create the database, all we can do is create,update,drop tables

Comment: This solution also is not correct, in case if you have some particular  configuration for your database, like encoding, permissions etc..

Comment: Dangerous to use. You can also loose your database settings that you forgot to check...

Comment: Easiest alternative ever.

Comment: can use 'show create database database_name' before running this

Comment: This is obviously what is not something people are looking for when they get stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer does not work for databases that have large numbers of tables, e.g. Drupal databases.  Instead, see the script here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12917793/1507877
which does work on MySQL 5.5.  CAUTION: Around line 11, there is a "WHERE table_schema = SCHEMA();"   This should instead be "WHERE table_schema = 'INSERT NAME OF DB INTO WHICH IMPORT WILL OCCUR';"

Comment: By the way, if doing Drupal development, the really easy way to do this is with the drush command line tool.  The command is:  drush sql-drop