# MySQL procedure to delete all data in the DB

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have tried to write MySQL procedure to delete all data in the DB:

MySQL Server version 5.5.20

It looks like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_data_like(pattern VARCHAR(255), db VARCHAR(255))
begin
    DECLARE truncate_table VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT(db, '.', info.table_name)
        FROM information_schema.tables AS info
        WHERE info.table_schema=db AND info.table_name LIKE pattern;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur1;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO truncate_table;
        IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;

        PREPARE stmt FROM truncate_table;

        EXECUTE stmt;
        DROP PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL drop_data_like('%%', DATABASE());

DROP PROCEDURE drop_data_like;
```

And as the result it has showed error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 16: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@truncate_table;
    IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;

    PREPARE ' at line 13
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use `TRUNCATE`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403662/drop-all-tables

Comment: Our structure of DB is not static so we need simple way to remove all data but structure must be stay untouched

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem and this works now:

```
-- Server version   5.5.20

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_data_like(pattern VARCHAR(255), db VARCHAR(255))
begin
    DECLARE truncate_table VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE ', db, '.', info.table_name)
        FROM information_schema.tables AS info
        WHERE info.table_schema=db AND info.table_name LIKE pattern;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur1;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO truncate_table;
        SET @sql = truncate_table;
        IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DROP PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL drop_data_like('%%', DATABASE());

DROP PROCEDURE drop_data_like;



/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the structure but just get rid of data, then it would be easier to do a mysqldump with structure only (the -d option), then drop the database and recreate it with the mysqldump ouptut.

```
mysqldump -d -h localhost -u user -ppassword databasename > dumpfile.sql

mysqlimport -u root -ppassword databasename dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: Your `mysqldump` command makes sense, but your import command is wrong. You should do something like this to import the schema: `mysql -u root -ppassword databasename < dumpfile.sql`

Comment: @Ike.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Was thinking "import" and confused myself.