# Clear database at startup while using flyway

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, flyway

In my case, I'm using spring-boot with gradle and added flyway by simply putting `compile   'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'` to the `build.gradle`.

For a simulator run, which is in `test`, I would like to clear the database before each run. I've put a [reset script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403662/how-to-drop-all-mysql-tables-from-the-command-line) in `/src/test/resources/db/migration/V1.0__Reset.sql` (with the real init sql-script at `/src/main/resources/db/migration/V1.1__Init.sql`), but receive a SyntaxException due to the reset script, which doesn't occur when I run it from the MySQL Workbench.

How can I reset or clear the database at startup?

**-- UPDATE --**

I've tried to use a Spring `DataSourceInitializer`, but it seems Flyway scripts are executed before the DS init, so it results in Hibernate Syntax error because the tables aren't found.

```
@Resource
DataSource ds;

@Bean
public DataSourceInitializer dbInit() throws FileNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {
        public DataSourceInitializer dbInit() throws FileNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {
        DataSourceInitializer re = new DataSourceInitializer();
        re.setDataSource(ds);
        re.setEnabled(true);

        String str = "classpath:sql/V1.0__Reset.sql";
        URL url = ResourceUtils.getURL(str);
        org.springframework.core.io.Resource resi = new PathResource(url.toURI());
        // new org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource(str)
        re.setDatabasePopulator(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(resi));
        return re;
    }
```

Comment: What's in the reset script and what's the syntax error?

Comment: The script from the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403662/how-to-drop-all-mysql-tables-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 3):

Go for Flyway.clean(). It does exactly what you want. No need to write your own reset script.

Comment: This is a similar questions (at least the solution is): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745995/execute-sth-after-or-before-bean-is-created

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ApplicationRunner` to run just after the startup and inside it do whatever you want with flyway. You'll also probably want to run `migrate` after `clean`:

```java
@Component
public class CleanDatabase implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Flyway flyway;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        flyway.clean();
        flyway.migrate();
    }

}
```