# Execute sth. after or before bean is created

Tags: spring, initialization, spring-boot

I use `spring-boot` with flyway and a datasource, so both beans are automatically configured by spring-boot. Now I would like to execute foo(some code / a SQL script) either directly after the datasource  or before the flyway bean is initialized.

How can I configure externally -preferably with annotations- that flyway dependsOn fooBean or that post construct of the datasource foo should be called?

Is it the 'better' approach trying to alter the bean initialization order or  registering an ApplicationListener (if possible)?

Comment: some code / a SQL script.

Comment: Do you mean "something"?

Comment: yes, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sth#Abbreviation

Comment: can't sth. be executed directly by flyway just with proper version? flyway can execute both SQL and java and also it supports out of order execution if needed.

Comment: Actually I would like to clean the database each time the application is started.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the only solution is to override the Flyway configuration and add the "clean" method call. So create your own FlywayConfig class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class FlywayConfig {

    @Autowired
    private FlywayProperties properties = new FlywayProperties();

    @Autowired(required = false)
    @FlywayDataSource
    private DataSource flywayDataSource;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
    public Flyway flyway() {
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        if (this.properties.isCreateDataSource()) {
            flyway.setDataSource(this.properties.getUrl(), this.properties.getUser(),
                    this.properties.getPassword(), this.properties.getInitSqls()
                            .toArray(new String[0]));
        }
        else if (this.flywayDataSource != null) {
            flyway.setDataSource(this.flywayDataSource);
        }
        else {
            flyway.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        }
        flyway.clean(); // <-- this drops the schema
        return flyway;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI there will be a more sane approach in the next spring boot (v1.3.x).  

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/ebccedcfdde14a64280aa0e3b5a8438bc84f6fd2

github issue to address: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1814