# Suggest a way to delete all the tables and make MySQL database empty in JavaFX

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

I developed a project in JavaFX. Its back-end is MySQL. For my project I created a database named 'project' in MySQL. Now this database contains 8 tables. I want to make the database empty when a button is pressed, that is delete all tables, not database. Should I have to empty each table and delete them or is there any other easy way to clear the database ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476765/mysql-drop-all-tables-ignoring-foreign-keys

Comment: Again, this has nothing to do with javafx. Please use the proper tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
DROP DATABASE project; CREATE DATABASE project;
```

longer way:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM project;
```

and iterate through the tables with

```
DROP TABLE project.<tablename>;
```

Comment: Can I delete if the database is not empty ?

Comment: Yeah, be careful with those commands. Normally the "working user" should not be allowed those commands, it should be task of a structure admin.

Comment: What do you mean by that ? Can you explain it a little further ?

Comment: You can define different users for the database (username/password for the MySQL-Connection), one can insert, delete, update and is used in the Web-App, the other user can also drop tables, drop databases, alter tables and so on. I just mean: be careful in which situations you fire a "DROP DATABASE" Command.

Answer (score -1):

(this will clear the database)

```
 Truncate table tableName;
```