# Delete all entities from database with gorm while ignoring foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I have multiple domain classes in my `Grails 3.0.9` application which have `many-to-many` relations to each other. When I want to delete all entities from the database I get an error saying:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`figure`, CONSTRAINT `FK_dbgwxhc7ggggypvmf967wvgfw` FOREIGN KEY (`fig_other_table_id`) REFERENCES `other_table` (`id`)); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`figure`, CONSTRAINT `FK_dbgwxhc7ggggypvmf967wvgfw` FOREIGN KEY (`fig_other_table_id`) REFERENCES `other_table` (`id`))
```

Is there a way using `GORM` to ignore foreign key contraints this time?

I've tried to tell GORM in the domain class to cascade delete like this:

```
static mapping = {
        figOtherTable cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
}
```

like descriped in the [GORM docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html), but that's not working for me (or I am missing something).

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8248281/2514164) that you can tell MySQL to ignore foreign key constraints by executing:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0
```

Is there a way doing this with GORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that GORM is not able to cascade deletes in a many-to-many relationship. You have to handle deletes on your own...

This Link might help you as well http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/