# Delete all tables from the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using SQL Server management studio 2008,  here my problem is i want to delete all my tables in one particular database ,how can i do this anybody tell me .

Comment: drop the DB and recreate it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL DROP all tables, ignoring foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476765/mysql-drop-all-tables-ignoring-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 0):

> In object explorer, navigate to the database you're interested in. Expand it out and click on the Tables folder. Hit F7 to bring up the Object Explorer Details. Select the tables you want to delete and press the delete key.